# apollo no recibe imágenes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

estoy tratando de subir imagenes a mi backend mediante apollo, este es mi schema de graphql:

```
scalar upload

type Mutation {
  to_post(data_post: InputTo_post!): ResponsePost
}

input InputTo_post {
  text: String
  image: Upload
}

type ResponsePost {
  error: Boolean
  success: Boolean
  message: String
}
```

*Utilizo el `scalar` por que como mis esquemas estan construidos mediante `addResolversToSchema` y `stitchSchemas`.

cuando recibo la peticion en el backend muestro por consola los resultados y me devuelve lo siguiente

```
{ data_post: { text: '', image: [ {} ] } }
```

el campo `text` no importa por que lo recivo bien, pero el campo image no esta devolviendo las imagenes que envie, esta es la logica del frontend donde envio las imagenes al backend

```
const [post, setPost] = useState<{ text: string, image: File }>({ text: "", image: [] });

const handleInputFile = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const { files } = event.currentTarget;
  if (files)
    for (let i = 0; i < Array.from(files).length; i++) {
      let element: File = files[i];
      setPost(prev => ({...prev, image: [...prev.image, element]}));
    }
};

const submitPost = useCallback(() => {
  TO_POST({ variables: { dataPost: post } })
  .then(({ data }) => {
    const { success, error, message } = data.to_post;
    if (success) {
      setPost({text: "", image: [] });
      enqueueSnackbar(message, { variant: "success" });
    } else if (error) {
      enqueueSnackbar(message, { variant: "error" });
    }
  });
},[TO_POST, enqueueSnackbar, post]);


return(
  <form onSubmit={submitPost}>
    <input
      onChange={handleInputFile}
      type="file"
      accept="image/*,video/*"
      id="img"
      className={classes.inputFile}
      multiple
      maxLength={5}
    />
  </form>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola me di cuenta de que tienes un error en tu codigo ya que en esta parte no esta bien :

```
<form onSubmit={submitPost}>
    <input
      onChange={handleInputFile}
      type="file"
      accept="image/*,video/*"
      id="img"
      className={classes.inputFile}
      multiple
      maxLength={5}
    />
  </form>
)
```

deveria ser :

```
<div onSubmit={submitPost}>
    <input
      onChange={handleInputFile}
      type="file"
      accept="image/*,video/*"
      id="img"
      className={classes.inputFile}
      multiple
      maxLength={3}
    />
  </div>
)
```

Espero ayudar.

Comment: Sería bueno añadir una explicación acerca del cambio del form por un div.